# Is the Model part of Codeigniter considered an ORM-layer?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, orm, doctrine

I'm creating a project in Codeigniter, and I'm looking in to implementing a ORM-layer between the database and site. I have tried out Doctrine, but it feels rather redundant as you are creating Models, just as you normally would (extending CI_Model).

Is not using the CI_Model class enough to make my database interactions object-oriented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the initial question...no, it is not a full-on ORM layer.

There is also DataMapper if you don't like Doctrine.  I guess it may feel redundant because you are extending the functionality of CI because it doesn't use a true ORM by default.

Honestly if I were going to use CodeIgniter, I would just stick with using Active Record and CI's default functionality...if I wanted a framework with a true ORM, I would pick one that ships with one.  That's just my opinion though.